# Modify timestamps to sequence per ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe (Python 3.5.1) with a timestamp column and an ID column.

```
   Timestamp                ID   
0  2016-04-01T00:15:36.688  123  
1  2016-04-01T00:12:52.688  123  
2  2016-04-01T00:35:41.688  543  
3  2016-04-01T00:01:12.688  543  
4  2016-03-31T23:50:59.688  123  
5  2016-04-01T01:05:52.688  543
```

I would like to sequence the timestamps per ID.

```
   Timestamp                ID   Sequence
0  2016-04-01T00:15:36.688  123  3
1  2016-04-01T00:12:52.688  123  2
2  2016-04-01T00:35:41.688  543  2
3  2016-04-01T00:01:12.688  543  1
4  2016-03-31T23:50:59.688  123  1
5  2016-04-01T01:05:52.688  543  3
```

What is the best way to order the timestamps per ID, and generate a sequence number unique to each ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [sort_values()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [groupby()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [cumcount()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
In [10]: df['Sequence'] = df.sort_values('Timestamp').groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                Timestamp   ID  Sequence
0 2016-04-01 00:15:36.688  123         3
1 2016-04-01 00:12:52.688  123         2
2 2016-04-01 00:35:41.688  543         2
3 2016-04-01 00:01:12.688  543         1
4 2016-03-31 23:50:59.688  123         1
5 2016-04-01 01:05:52.688  543         3
```

Comment: Thats not accounting for the timestamp though. For instance, 1 is after 2 in terms of time.

Comment: @Tobias121, yes,  thanks! I've also noticed that and have corrected my answer... ;)